# Send personalized email with python

Tags: python, html, email, automation

I'm a beginner trying to send a personalized email with python.

```
import smtplib, ssl

def read_creds():
    user = passw = ""
    with open("credentials.txt", "r") as f:
        file = f.readlines()
        user = file[0].strip()
        passw = file[1].strip()

    return user, passw


port = 465

sender, password = read_creds()

receive = sender

message = """\
Subject: Python

This is from python!
"""

context = ssl.create_default_context()

print("Starting to send")
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", port, context=context) as server:
    server.login(sender, password)
    server.sendmail(sender, receive, message)

print("email sent.")
```

I want to add a personalized code (which could be, for example, 123456) to every email, but from the tutorial I've read I can't understand how to do it.

Comment: What is your actual question?  How to _generate_ a unique code?  Or how to _include_ such a code in the email body?

Comment: Should the code be unique for each email or just unique to you, i.e. an identifier?

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify the way to retrieve a list of contacts from a file or from the database. For the simplicity I'll use an array.

Start with updating your message to support custom messages:

```
message = """
Subject: Message subject

Hi {name}, you have got a personal message!
"""
```

Then update the logic behind sending the emails and add recipients into the array (in real life use the DB or file):

```
recipients = [{"email":"email1@aol.com", "name":"Misha"},{"email":"email2@aol.com", "name":"Andrey"}]

print("Starting to send")
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", port, context=context) as server:
    server.login(sender, password)
    for recipient in recipients:
        server.sendmail(sender, recipient["email"], message.format(name=name))
```

Comment: server.sendmail(sender, recipient["receive"], message.format(pCode=pCode))    This is my updated code, but when I run it, with pCode being '123456', I get this error.       UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe8' in position 95: ordinal not in range(128)